# How to add a handler for a button in plugin?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions

I am working on my first plugin, and I am having some confusion. I am trying to figure out how to set a handler for a button on my plugin UI. Here is how the button is displayed:

```
<li class="upload-files-sec"><a id="upload_image_button" href="#" title="" data-tooltip="Upload Image" data-placement="bottom" class="upload-btn"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i></a>
</li>
```

The confusion is how I am supposed to link that to an action. I know using Jquery I could do something like this:

```
 $('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {
//Do action here.
}
```

But what about php? If I had some php I wanted the button to execute, how would run it when the button is clicked?

Comment: Some which PHP? PHP is server side language, you would need to either proceed to URL or perform Ajax request to one.

Comment: Agree with Rarst. You probably need [AJAX](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: I figured that would be the only way to do it. Ajax it is then.